# Output of the multilevel dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an array with data:

```
$arr=[1=>['id'=>1,'value'=>"Main",'id_parent'=>0],
      2=>['id'=>2,'value'=>"Port",'id_parent'=>0,'children'=>[
         3=>['id'=>3,'value'=>"Auto",'id_parent'=>2],
         4=>['id'=>4,'value'=>"Busy",'id_parent'=>2],
         5=>['id'=>5,'value'=>"Sury",'id_parent'=>2,'children'=>[
            6=>['id'=>6,'value'=>"Truk",'id_parent'=>5]]]]]];
```

I can not get it out like a tree menu... My code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu-items" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
<?php 
function createTemplateMenu($value){
    $menu = "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
    if (isset($value['children'])) $menu .= "<li class='dropdown-submenu'>" . showCat($value['children']) . "</li>";
    $menu .= "<li><a href=''>{$value['value']}</a></li></ul>";
    return $menu;
}
function showCat($data){
    $string = "";
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $string .= createTemplateMenu($item);
    }
    return $string;
}
echo showCat($arr);?>
</li>
```

On html it looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ob8yo5nL/ It's not displayed as needed, I'm just an example of a code sample.

Comment: In which platform you are working (core phpm WordPress or any other)?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a recursion - a recursive function that calls itself, like this:

```
function showCat($data){
    $string = "";
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $string .= createTemplateMenu($item);

        if(array_key_exists("children", $item) && is_array($item['children'])) {
            $string .= showCat($item['children']);
        }

    return $string;
}
```

That's just an example. You need to do a little bit more work and rethink your rendering function, too (`createTemplateMenu`), but recursion is the solution in this case.

See: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-recursion/

Comment: I do not know how to properly hang classes 'dropdown-menu' and 'dropdown-submenu' - this is the whole problem

Comment: with 'ul' and 'li' without classes I know how output